# Derivative of integral defining delta function: Lost minus sign?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I am going through my lecture notes of a theoretical physics class and stumbled across something that irritates me. The line in question is

$$-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\left(x-y\right)t}\ \mathrm{d}t=2\pi\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}\delta\left(y-x\right)$$

Notice how

1. The minus sign seems to disappear
2. The variable of the derivative changes

I cannot really make sense of this. Is this simply wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: The line isn't even true. It lacks a factor $2\pi$:
$$\int e^{ixy} dx = 2\pi \, \delta(y).$$

Comment: @md2perpe I forgot the factor, its in my notes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From
$$
\int e^{i(x-y)t} dt = 2\pi \, \delta(x-y) = 2\pi \, \delta(y-x)
$$
we get
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \int e^{i(x-y)t} dt 
= 2\pi \, \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \delta(y-x) 
= -2\pi \, \delta'(y-x) 
= -2\pi \, \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \delta(y-x) 
.
$$

Comment: That one step in the middle was really hard to see, especially coming from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3743836)...

Comment: It's just the chain rule. The minus sign comes from the inner derivative.